# Syncing docker-compose remote context state across multiple developers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Got a question about docker contexts, Fellas.

- Assuming we make a docker-compose context for a remote machine (i.e., `docker context create aaa --docker "host=ssh://root@1.1.1.1")
- And build it and run it on the remote machine (i.e., `docker-compose --context aaa up -d`)
- Now the machine is running. Let's say I left my computer and my colleague using their computer wants to check some logs for the machine (i.e., run `docker-compose --context aaa logs`)

How can we sync the state of contexts? Should I prepare a file to run the first `docker context create aaa` command for them, and after that, docker-compose can recognize the running machine?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a bash file with a bunch of `docker context create blah --docker "host=ssh://blah@ip"` commands that other devs can run and it'll sync the state for them. I know there are `docker context export/import` commands, but the format was not clean and it produces a file per context, which is subpar.